# Rename "Comment" in edit review queue to "Edit Summary" (which is also what it is called when editing a post)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, wording

I have noticed that when you submit an edit, the edit summary is called "Edit Summary", while when reviewing edits it's simply called "Comment". I feel like it would be good to make them both read the same thing. Probably "Edit Summary" is the best option. See images below

**Justification**:

1. The word "Comment" is a bit misleading and doesn't reflect what the box is actually for
2. Using different terms can lead to confusion when referring to that "thing". Personal story:

   Often when reviewing, I choose the "This edit causes harm" option,
   so I can elaborate why I think the edit was bad. Before noticing
   this, if I wanted to refer to the text the suggester provided, I
   called it a "Comment", which I am sure has been confusing for some (since they don't see that term).

**It is called "Comment" in the review queue**:

[image: Copy in Review Queue - "Comment"]

**While it is called "Edit Summary" when editing**:

[image: Copy While Editing- "Edit Summary"]

Answer (score 5):

I'm for preserving the naming from the original action to the subsequent screen to prevent context switching and to preserve clarity.  Easy fix - shipping to prod soon.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this change; In this case it can also be called as: ***Justification of the POST Edition:*** what you are trying to do is justify your action or evaluation of an edition. in other software / implementations they name it as ***Memo!*** to this field, it can also be called this way. and it is the equivalent of the notice left by someone who passed and reviewed the post.

Comment: One thing I like about "Justification" is that it would make it clear that users should justify why this is a good edit. I am currently struggling with a guy who keeps suggesting edits and every edit summary is just "Code refacto", which means I am forced to deduce why he did what he did on every suggested edit.. So this basically boils down to describing what you did (Edit Summary) against why you did it (Edit Justification)

Comment: @Neuron Personally; If a post (the Question) includes code, the only reason why the code should be touched is because the user pasted it as is and did not format it.
however, there are languages like python where not even indentation should be touched; since it has a lot of value for the execution of MREs. this should be a norm.

Comment: @Neuron The User who posted the POST is responsible for presenting the Readable Code, not the community.
if a post (the Answer) includes code, the same precept must be applied; even if there is an option in which the code can be refactored; it should leave the code from the original answer and show the additional code from the refactoring.
But like I said this is my personal suggestion; and I try to promote it on SO's Spanish site; if they want to take it to a FAQ or help site that would be fine.