# Remove minimum length restriction when moderators edit a revision comment (a.k.a. edit summary)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, revisions-list, edit-summary

A moderator can edit a post's [revision comment (a.k.a. edit summary)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371514/241919). However, when the text is too short, they get an error message that says:

> [image]
>
> Your edit summary must be at least 10 characters.

On the other hand, users with the "edit questions and answers" privilege can put a *1-letter edit summary* if they want (not really a good idea, but to show the comparison...).

AFAIK, this tool has rare use cases, so I don't think removing the minimum length makes it more abusable.

Comment: I'd really like to be able to put in 0 characters and have it spit out "edited N characters in body" or something like it would if you created the revision.